# Как оптимизировать поиск массива в массиве

Tags: c#, алгоритм, list

Есть два файла - исходный `file.txt` и список стоп слов `dic.txt`. Я с помощью простого алгоритма сделал поиск и замену слов, однако операция идет очень долго. Какое место здесь самое узкое? Как можно оптимизировать алго?

```
 var dic = File.ReadAllLines("dic.txt").ToList();
 var file = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt").ToList();
 progressBar1.Maximum = file.Count;

 for (int i = 0; i < file.Count; i++) {
  progressBar1.Value++;
  for (int j = 0; j < dic.Count; j++) {
   file[i] = Regex.Replace(file[i], dic[j].Split('\t')[0], dic[j].Split('\t')[1]);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Можно вычислять `dic[j].Split()` только один раз за цикл, сохранять в переменную, а потом использовать ее в `Regex.Replace`.

Comment: @arrowd, а еще лучше один раз при считывании из файла

Comment: @Grundy Не улавливаю как это поможет.

Comment: Прочитайте целевой файл в одну строку, весь

Comment: @arrowd, ты предлагаешь делать split один раз, но каждую итерацию цикла, я предлагаю делать split - вообще один раз

Comment: @VladD, и сразу глобальную замену всему?

Comment: @Grundy Как его сделать только один раз, если нужно каждую строку сплитить?

Comment: @Grundy: Угу. Чем организовывать поиск текста вручную, пусть этим занимается регулярка.

Comment: @VladD Автор каждую строку одного файла заменяет на шаблоны из соответствующей строки другого файла. Тут один фиг разбивать по строкам. Поэтому читать файл целиком нет смысла.

Comment: @Radzhab А какого размера файлы? Не гигабайтные, случаем?

Comment: @arrowd, при чтении dic из файла, сразу и разбить перед вызовом ToList.  При этом в цикле `for` split уже будет не нужен

Comment: @arrowd: Ну вроде есть? Можно попробовать спрофилировать.

Comment: @arrowd, _Автор каждую строку одного файла заменяет на шаблоны из соответствующей строки другого файла._ - на самом деле не совсем так, он пробует применить к каждой строке все шаблоны. Если файлы не велики, то регулярка по полному файлу вполне может иметь смысл учитывая что регулярка так же способна работать со строками

Comment: Можно словарь организовать в виде дерева.

Comment: @user3195373: Тогда уж в виде Hashset, он встроен в стандартную библиотеку. Или вы имеете в виду поисковое дерево? Тогда наверное лучше регулярки, они именно поисковое дерево и строят.

Comment: @VladD ага, имел в виду поисковое. Перед сравнениями с файлом, сканируем весь словарь, и строим дерево. С регекспами не совсем понял. Все равно же массив слов всего словаря пробегать надо.

Comment: @user3195373: Ну, пробежаться по списку слов, составить из них регулярку `(слово1)|(слово2)|(...`. При компиляции регулярка по идее построит такое же поисковое дерево.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пока благородные доны в комментариях предлагают разные умные варианты, я предлагаю попробовать по рабоче-крестьянски: заменить `Regex.Replace` на `string.Replace` - у меня в тесте ускорение примерно десятикратное.

```
var dic = File.ReadAllLines("dic.txt");
var file = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt");
progressBar1.Maximum = file.Length;

for (int i = 0; i < file.Length; i++)
{
    progressBar1.Value++;
    for (int j = 0; j < dic.Length; j++)
    {
        var splitted = dic[j].Split('\t');
        file[i] = file[i].Replace(splitted[0], splitted[1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: зависит от содержимого `dic`

Comment: @Grundy, ждём, пока ОП уточнит размеры файлов и словаря.

Comment: @Radzhab, я могу предложить разные варианты кода, как с чтением всего текста сразу и заменой по нему, так и с распараллеливанием. Но какой именно вариант выбрать, зависит от размеров исходного текста и словаря. Так что напишите их.

Comment: Не могли бы показать для нас и способ с распараллеливанием)?

Comment: @Radzhab - кхм... Я тут потестил немного. Пришёл к выводу, что игра не стоит свеч. Распараллеливание выгодно будет только на реально огромных объёмах данных (мне не охота ждать минуты для подтверждения). Главная проблема - необходимость синхронизации обращения к прогрессбару (так как он не потокобезопасный). Это съедает выгоду и сильно усложняет код. Как соберусь с мыслями (и время найду), дополню ответ с внятным объяснением.